# Compatibility of US Rock Band equipment with Australian Wii? (RB3 in particular)

Tags: nintendo-wii, rock-band-3

I want to pick up the wireless keyboard for Rock Band 3 for Wii.  In Australia, as far as I can tell, only EB Games has imported it, and it costs nearly $200AU for the pleasure.

Including shipping, it would only be about $100AU to order the keyboard from the States.  However, PAL/NTSC compatibility and region-locking issues are making me uneasy in that regard.

Obviously, the game itself will be region locked (and I'll probably buy that here), but what about the peripherals?

Comment: I would have thought that the peripherals wouldn't have any region locking - but I have no evidence for this which is why I'm not suggesting it as an answer!

Comment: I've been snooping around the forums and have found hands on experience that there is no problem for RB2 (lost the link for that one) and a pretty ardent claim that this is also the case for RB3 (http://www.rockband.com/forums/showthread.php?200939-Rock-Band-3-International-Compatability&p=4029107&viewfull=1#post4029107).

I won't post this as an answer as it's still not decisive, only convincing.

Comment: @Aubergine One thing that makes me nervous is that I have the feeling (with no particular evidence) that the Wii peripherals may be more region-locked than PS3/Xbox...  Particularly given the versions that required a Wiimote to be installed into them to work...

Comment: Well, since nobody seems to know, I decided to order it and see what happens. It's ordered, I guess I'm about to find out. :S

Comment: On the plus side, you'll be able to answer your own question and march mankind forward. I really hope it does work out for you, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works!

(Caveat: Thus far I've only been playing on non-Pro easy mode, but if that's working fine I can't imagine that the other buttons are going to cause issues...)